# Do purchased weapons come with a sheath?

Tags: weapons, equipment, pathfinder-2e

A sheath, found in the adventure gear table on pg.288 of the core rules, cost 1cp. It is described on pg.291:

> A sheath or scabbard lets you easily carry a weapon on your person

Many of the Class kits, found on the next page, come with one sheath included.

> **Fighter**
>
> ...Price, Bulk, &c.
>
> **Gear** adventurer's pack, grappling hook, ***sheath***

(emph. mine.)

Does this imply you need to buy a 1cp sheath along with every weapon, or do weapons you purchase from the weapons table automatically come with one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Officially, no.

The only instances of the word "sheath" in the PHB are

- p286: The Sap weapon description about being a leather sheath wrapped around a lead rod
- p288: Adventuring Gear table
- P289: Class Kits descriptions include the sheath item
- p291: The description of the sheath item

  - notably, this is the only instance of the word scabbard in the document
- p602: The Storm Flash magic weapon describes that it causes storm clouds to gather overhead when out of its sheath

Based on the description of the sheath item and the lack of weapons indicating that they come with one, you have to buy them.

---

### My recommendation

As a player and GM of Pathfinder first edition (and other RPG's), I don't see any point to track copper pieces after 1st level. It is notable that currency is generally more valuable in Pathfinder 2e than it was previously; however, as a GM, I would still only require players to spend the money for their initial equipment and any weapon they buy very early in the campaign (when that level of currency is still significant), but allow them to hand-wave the cost in the future.

This, of course, does not apply to organized Pathfinder Society play.